# How do I interpret [blank] per unit [blank] per unit [blank]?

Tags: calculus, fractions, infinitesimals

For example, if I have the *energy per unit time per unit area*, do I formally interpret that as:

$$\frac{E}{(dt)(dA)}$$

and intuitively interpret it as how much energy is in an infinitesimal area in an infinitesimal interval of time?

Comment: The answer is yes on both parts there, much like acceleration is unit of distance per unit of time per unit of time

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks!!!

Comment: Yep while it might seem superfluous it can actually be very descriptive. This kind of construct is found frequently in physics

Comment: Yea I'm a physics major and I see this a lot. I always assumed what it meant but I wanted some confirmation.

Comment: Myself too, reason why I like to answer the physics questions here (and physics stack exchange) often.